# Disable text effects on tab labels in Firefox with ColorfulTabs

Tags: firefox

It seems a recent ColorfulTabs update includes new text effects on tab labels that makes the labels unreadable in any of my installed themes and causes the current tab to annoyingly flash whenever I mouse-over any tab.

I've looked through the plugin options but haven't found an obvious way to disable this new feature. Have I missed something, or do I need to remove the plugin entirely to get rid of this?

EDIT: Oh, good. [I'm not crazy.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/colorfultabs/reviews/444576/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this feature is either removed or disabled by default in the [18.1 version available from the Binary Turf website](https://www.binaryturf.com/files/extensions/colorfultabs/colorfultabs18.1.xpi) - not currently available from the Mozilla plugins library. Though I'd like to know where the switch is to toggle this feature, if there is one, updating the plugin has the desired effect for me.

Comment: Sometimes, I wish I could up-vote myself. Had to look this up again after a re-install. Good to have my old notes here.